# It it possible to write accented letter in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

For some reason, this doesn't work :

```
"pequeño"
```

Which will return as :

```
"pequeo"
```

When writing it, or pasting it, it looks like this :

```
 "pequeo"+FFC3\U+FFB1o"
```

But still returns with the incorrect letter.

My `database.yml` :

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: UTF8
  database: test-postgres_development
  pool: 5
```

My terminal prints it fine. Its just console that will not work.

Comment: Are you on MacOS?  Are you using `Terminal.app` to run commands from the console?

Comment: output of the `locale` command on the terminal?

Comment: `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Hmm, For me in the console I'm able to put special accented characters into the terminal no problem.  Have you been using the mac keyboard key to add the `ñ`?   `option+n  n`.  Does this work from the terminal: `echo "ñ"` (not in a rails console).  If yes, does this work in `irb`:  `test = "ñ"`?

Comment: From the terminal it works, from console it returns blank, and pastes as what look like the unicode. Yes, using a mac keyboard.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?  When you say "return as", do you mean that after saving to the DB and restoring, that's the value?  Or do you mean that simply assigning a variable in the console loses the ñ?

Comment: Yah simply writing it as a string directly to console, and it kludges. Ruby 1.9.3-p385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was trying to get pry to understand this.

What I did was :

```
brew install readline
brew link readline

mate ~/.rvmrc
```

Then add this to the file :

```
export ruby_configure_flags="--with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4"
```

Then reinstall my ruby.

BLAM! I GOT AN "ñ"

Comment: confirmed, Thx! with rbenv, run: RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install <RUBY_VERSION>